# image preview basicLightbox

Tags: javascript, lightbox

The image in gallery should open in modal,but downloading it and idk why.

Here is criteria to be followed:
-A combination of script and basicLightbox modal window library styles. Use the jsdelivr CDN and add links to minified (.min) library files to your project.
-Opening a modal window after clicking on a gallery item. To do this, see the documentation and examples.
-Changing the value of the  element's src attribute in a modal window before opening. Use the ready-made modal window tag with the image from the basicLightbox library examples.

Here is GitHub page:
https://bazky.github.io/goit-js-hw-07/01-gallery.html

Here is HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Image gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/common.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/basiclightbox@5.0.4/dist/basicLightbox.min.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><a href="index.html">Go back</a></p>

    <div id="prev">
      <div class="gallery">
        <div class="gallery__item">
          <a
            class="gallery__link"
            href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/14/16/43/rchids-4202820_1280.jpg"
          >
            <img
              width="340"
              class="gallery__image"
              src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/14/16/43/rchids-4202820__480.jpg"
              data-source="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/14/16/43/rchids-4202820_1280.jpg"
              alt="Hokkaido Flower"
            />
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/basiclightbox@5.0.4/dist/basicLightbox.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/01-gallery.js" type="module"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is JS:

```
import { galleryItems } from "./gallery-items.js";

import * as basicLightbox from "basiclightbox";
const gallery = document.querySelector(".gallery");

function createGalleryItem(item) {
  const galleryItem = document.querySelector(".gallery__item");
  const image = galleryItem.querySelector(".gallery__image");
  const link = galleryItem.querySelector(".gallery__link");

  image.src = item.preview;
  image.dataset.source = item.original;
  image.alt = item.description;
  link.href = item.original;

  return galleryItem;
}

function renderGalleryItems() {
  const galleryItemsElements = galleryItems.map(createGalleryItem);
}

function onGalleryItemClick(event) {
  const imageSrc = event.target.dataset.source;
  const instance = basicLightbox.create(`
    <img src="${imageSrc}" width="800" height="600">
  `);
  instance.show();
}

function addGalleryItemsListener() {
  gallery.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    if (event.target.classList.contains("gallery__image")) {
      onGalleryItemClick(event);
    }
  });
}

const prev = document.getElementById("prev");
prev.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  preventDeafult();
});

renderGalleryItems();
addGalleryItemsListener();
onGalleryItemClick();
createGalleryItem();

console.log(galleryItems);
```

Comment: My guess would be, that this probably has something to do with the source of the images you are using there. `https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/14/16/43/rchids-4202820_1280.jpg` responds with a `content-type: binary/octet-stream` header, instead of one saying this was actually a JPEG image; and if you enter that URL into your browser address bar directly, it will not _show_ the image, but show the download dialog. Try this with images from a different source - one that isn't trying to "force a download" from their end already.

Comment: there are no event handlers on your working demo - just open the devtools, prints an error `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "basiclightbox". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`.

Comment: I have a task where is data array galleryItems 
`export const galleryItems = [
  {
    preview:
      'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/14/16/43/rchids-4202820__480.jpg',
    original:
      'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/14/16/43/rchids-4202820_1280.jpg',
    description: 'Hokkaido Flower',
  }];`

Comment: Maybe try some alternative, for example, Fancybox looks great and has tons of examples - https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Answer (score 0):

You tried to use both approaches:

1. NPM (node ​​package manager for Node.js).

first of all it needs to install package basiclightbox, after that you can use imports in your JS-script like

- import SimpleLightbox from 'simplelightbox';
- import 'simplelightbox/dist/simple-lightbox.min.css';

2. CDN (Content Delivery Network) In this case it necessary adding specific import into your HTML page.

It is necessary to remove the import (**import * as basicLightbox from "basiclightbox";**) from the JS file.
It's enough for you to import in an html file of styles css and js. Means CDN (Content Delivery Network)

Comment: npm install [package-name]